# Adjust a scanned image with itextsharp or another library

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I need to adjust scanned pages that are skewed. I'll have to do this with up to 200 PDF documents per day, so it needs to be automated. I'm writing to you if you know of any method from the itextsharp library, or any other, that is able to identify the degree of skew of the page and correct it later.

I have developed the rest of the procedure, which is about printing information over the document. I only need the part of the page adjustment so that the information is not misplaced.

Comment: In this context the PDF is merely a container for the individual page scans. Thus, you most likely should look for some bitmap image manipulation libraries to unskew the scans. You use iText only to extract and re-inject bitmap images.

Answer (score 1):

PDF images are images in a container just like a zip file so you need to burst the PDF into images to manipulate them quickly and reinsert.
That itself is not an easy task but there are many tools to convert or extract pages rapidly. The core problem is how to parse modified images such as cropping distorted boundaries or scanned edges etc. and here you need to try different tools. Your challenge is keeping image size same as before.

So use either a deskew script in an image editor OR more simply a CLI/GUI deskewer since you dont say which OS I will offer cross platform Deskew, on my slow machine one image (see below) took 1/2 minute so 120/hr but this 32bit netbook runs on coal. here is a deliberate bad example (not normal for PDF output but highlight the requirements. Per below CLI command `deskew32 -o out.png in.jpg` its easy and if needed can give info rather than image for downstream usage in PDF related manipulation.

```
Preparing input image (2.jpg [3024x4032/R8G8B8])
Calculating skew angle...
Skew angle found [deg]: 3.255
Rotating image...
```

[image]

Deskew is a command line tool for deskewing scanned text documents. It uses Hough transform to detect "text lines" in the image. As an output, you get an image rotated so that the lines are horizontal.

You can use different ways so to compare two images say to get a mean value you can script cli here using cmd

```
@echo off
deskew -g d file1.png|find "[deg]" > out1.txt
deskew -g d file2.png|find "[deg]" >> out1.txt
type NUL > out2.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A in (out1.txt) do echo %%B >> out2.txt
```

Gives the two angles and if you need the average you simply add and divide the result by number of images.

```
  Supported file formats
    Input:  BMP, JPG, PNG, JNG, GIF, DDS, TGA, PBM, PGM, PPM, PAM, PFM, PSD, TIF
    Output: BMP, JPG, PNG, JNG, GIF, DDS, TGA, PGM, PPM, PAM, PFM, PSD, TIF
```

[image]

https://github.com/galfar/deskew for latest source and cli  binaries Arm/Linux/Mac & 32+64bit Win.

https://galfar.vevb.net/wp/download/DeskewGui-0.90.zip with 64bit Win (unsure if 32/64bit Linux/Mac) needs the CLI version too.

Note MS flags Gui as unusal to download ! but VirusTotal says its OK
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/24b1a575006310428d5fe0857fc2869c2ec3924dec2dd38e891e182de1484b08

There are many others for Deskew or [Dewarp](https://github.com/taeho-kil/Document-Image-Dewarping) but this should suffice for most bulk process cases and then use slower methods for any rejects. Dewarping takes twice as long but may be required in bad cases

[image]
[image]

Finally, a common complaint is the file size increases, well thats to be expected when dewarping or deskewing, as there will be more interpolated pixels in the output. If it bothers you use a different/second tool or set output format to decolourise into greyscale for OCR.